# Generic class EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

Good morning!

I am creating mapping for my entities - code first. The entities are:

```
        public abstract class PriceListRoot
        {
            public long Id { get; private set; }
        }

        public class XPriceListRoot : PriceListRoot
        {
            public ICollection<XPriceList> PriceLists { get; set; }
        }

        public class YPriceListRoot : PriceListRoot
        {
            public ICollection<YPriceList> PriceLists { get; set; }
        }

        public class ZPriceListRoot : PriceListRoot
        {
            public ICollection<ZPriceList> PriceLists { get; set; }
        }
```

In above code I would like to move PriceLists property into base class
so the solution would look like:

```
        public abstract class PriceListRoot<TPriceList>
        {
            public long Id { get; private set; }
            public ICollection<TPriceList> PriceLists { get; set; }
        }

        public class XPriceListRoot : PriceListRoot<XPriceList>
        {
        }

        public class YPriceListRoot : PriceListRoot<YPriceList>
        {
        }

        public class ZPriceListRoot : PriceListRoot<ZPriceList>
        {
        }
```

Above look better however how do I use fluent mapping to achive that. Current is:

```
public class PriceListMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PriceList>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PriceList> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("PriceLists");

            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            
            builder.HasDiscriminator<PriceListType>(nameof(PriceList.Type))
                .HasValue<ExchangePriceList>(PriceListType.X)
                .HasValue<DumpPriceList>(PriceListType.Y)
                .HasValue<ContainerRentalPriceList>(PriceListType.Z);
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to map generic class? Does anyone have expierience?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can create base implementation of `IEntityTypeConfiguration<PriceListRoot>` and inherit it for `PriceListRoot` descendants, but you can't map opened generic type to any table - this just doesn't make sense.

Comment: If `PriceListRoot` and `PriceList` must use TPH mapping model, then don't make `PriceListRoot` generic and use collection of base `PriceList` inside `PriceListRoot`.